# Python iterator when underlying object changes

Tags: python, iterator

I would like to know what's the general behaviour of an iterator if the underlaying object changes during the iteration.

Using a simple mutable list, it seems obvious: the iterator will try to follow on the next element if any, and send `StopIteration` if the end is reached.

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> a = iter(l)
>>> a.next()
0
>>> a.next()
1
>>> a.next()
2
>>> l[3]='a'
>>> a.next()
'a'
>>> a.next()
4
>>> del l[5]
>>> a.next()
6
>>> a.next()
7
>>> a.next()
8
>>> a.next()
9
>>> a.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

This is self-explanatory so far. What I don't understand is, that if I append a new element, the iterator will still return `StopIteration`.

```
>>> l.append(11)
>>> a.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

If I do the same before reaching the end:

```
>>> l=[1]
>>> a=iter(l)
>>> a.next()
1
>>> l.append(2)
>>> a.next()
2
```

How is this working under the hood, and what is the expected behaviour of a more complex mutable iterable object? (e.g. think of an object representing a graph, which then can be iterated over, using a traversal algorithm. What is supposed to happen then if nodes are added/removed while iterating?)

Comment: Answer: don't.  You ask what is supposed to happen in these conditions, but really you've stumbled across the answer yourself: such behaviour is typically ill-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a comment on that particular issue in [PEP 234](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/) (Iterators):

> Once a particular iterator object has raised StopIteration, will
>   it also raise StopIteration on all subsequent next() calls?
>
> Some say that it would be useful to require this, others say
>   that it is useful to leave this open to individual iterators.
>   Note that this may require an additional state bit for some
>   iterator implementations (e.g. function-wrapping iterators).
>
> Resolution: **once StopIteration is raised, calling it.next()
>   continues to raise StopIteration**.
>
> Note: this was in fact not implemented in Python 2.2; there are
>   many cases where an iterator's next() method can raise
>   StopIteration on one call but not on the next.  This has been
>   remedied in Python 2.3.

Comment: Is this like a suggestion or enforced by the language? If I implement an iterator class, do I need to take care that once __next__() returns StopIteration, it doesn't return anything else?

Comment: No, it's not enforced. You'll have to implement that behaviour yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are three typical behaviours of changing an object while iterating over it:

- the new data will be returned
- the new data will be ignored
- old data will be skipped

In other words: the actual behaviour is undefined.

Changing objects while iterating over them was such a common problem that in Python 3 the types `set` and `dict` (and possibly others) were changed to immediately raise an error if additions or removals were detected during iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There are some iterators that can yield more data even after a `StopIteration` has been raised; such iterators are [`considered broken`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

This does not mean the iterator is at fault -- it means that if you use such an iterator without caution you can end up with bugs and broken code.