# python: behaviors of iterator.next() when a container changes

Tags: python, iterator

```
    >>> a
    [1, 2, 3]
    >>> it = iter(a)
    >>> it.next()
    1
    >>> a.remove(1)
    >>> a
    [2, 3]
    >>> it.next()
    3
    >>>
```

in the above codes, why the second it.next() returns 3 but not 2?

note: this question is totally different from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987320/python-iterator-when-underlying-object-changes), which involves the StopIteration while the problem here is in the middle.

Comment: Because the iterator object remembers the last position.

Comment: @thefourtheye  if itertator remembers the last position, it should be `2`, isn't it?

Comment: Also see [Loop "Forgets" to Remove Some Items](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17299581); same principle applies.

Comment: @devnull no, it is a different question. I have read the answer and it doesn't give me any hints

Comment: @thefourtheye  it is `2`, not `s`

Comment: @thefourtheye it is not a duplicate, I have read that question, it is not the same as mine!

Comment: @dm03514   it is not a duplicate, I have read that question, it is not the same as mine